# How much numbers with even digit sum are between 1 and X?

Tags: combinatorics

I thought about counting from 1 to nearest round number for each digit of X (ex. X = 456, count from 1 to 400, from 400 to 450 and from 450 to 456), but I seem to be stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Of the numbers between $10a$ and $10a+9$, half have even digit sum. So for example half the numbers from $0$ to $459$ have even digit sum.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you noticed that I started at $0$. Starting at $1$, you get one fewer even digit sum.